# how to convert C++ while statmernt code with decrement into c# code

Tags: c#, c++

what I'm trying is to convert C++ piece of code

```
 while (n--) if (c & 0x80000000) c = (c << 1) ^ p2; else c <<= 1;
```

into c#

the whole code in c++ is:

```c++
#include "stdafx.h"
int main()
{
    unsigned long c, c2, p2, pol = 0xEDB88320;
    long n, k;
    {
        printf("CRC32 Adjuster (c) 2001 by RElf @ HHT/2\n");

        printf("Length of data: "); scanf_s("%ld", &n);

        printf("Offset to patch: "); scanf_s("%ld", &k);

        n = (n - k) << 3;

        printf("Current CRC32: 0x"); scanf_s("%x", &c);

        printf("Desired CRC32: 0x"); scanf_s("%x", &c2);

        c ^= c2;

        p2 = (pol << 1) | 1;

        while (n--) if (c & 0x80000000) c = (c << 1) ^ p2; else c <<= 1;

printf("XOR masks:%02X%02X%02X%02X\n", c & 0xff, (c >> 8) & 0xff, (c >> 16) & 0xff, c >> 24);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

what I have tried while translating into c#:

```
using System;

namespace crc323_fake
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            long c, c2, p2, pol = 0xEDB88320;
            long n, k;
            {
                n = 3440;
                k = 3436;
                n = (n - k) << 3;
                c = 0x73CBFFB5;
                c2 = 0x7D096252;
                c ^= c2;

                p2 = (pol << 1) | 1;
                while (n != 0)
                {
                    n = n - 1;
                    if( c &  0x80000000 )   // getting error here can't implicitly convert long to bool
                    {
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine("XOR masks:%02X%02X%02X%02X\n", c & 0xff, (c >> 8) & 0xff, (c >> 16) & 0xff, c >> 24);
                while (1) ;
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

I got rid of print statements and gave the straight value to the variables, and I'm stuck with

```
        while (n != 0)
        {
            n = n - 1;
            if( c &  0x80000000 )
          {
          }
        }
```

> if( c &  0x80000000 )
> gives me the error "can't implicitly convert long to bool"
> sorry if the question seems newbie, I'm really new at c#

Comment: `(c & 0x80000000) != 0`?

Comment: If I were you, I'd use `while (n > 0)` Maybe I'm just being paranoid, but it feels safer

Comment: @Jarod42 same error  with long to bool

Comment: @Jarod42 it doesnt work, gives me two errors

Comment: [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CUFHLC)...

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks works, you can post it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, non-nul integers convert to true.

So you have to be explicit here:

```
if (c &  0x80000000)
```

becomes

```
if ((c &  0x80000000) != 0)
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CUFHLC)